# Trying to use Lax-Milgram to solve a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let's say I have the problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u - b(x) \nabla u = f\\
u|_{\partial{\Omega}}=0
\end{cases}
$$

With $f, \text{div}(b) \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\Omega$ bounded. I would like to prove this function has a weak solution in $H_0 ^1 (\Omega)$. After applying integration by parts I should have that my PDE can be rewritten in weak form as:

$$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v = \int_{\Omega} (f + \text{div}(b))v \qquad \forall v \in H_0 ^1$$

Now, the LHS is a scalar product that induces an equivalent norm on $H_0 ^1$ thanks to Poincaré inequality, and the RHS can be viewed as a linear and continuous operator. Then Riesz's theorem should give me a unique solution. My question is: is this correct? And could you provide an example where instead of Riesz you have to use Lax-Milgram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your equation, you need extra assumption to use Lax-Milgram.

The bilinear you obtained is not quite right. The correct one should be as follows after you integrating by parts only for the second order term:

$$a(u, v):= (Lu,v) = \int_{\Omega}\big(\nabla u\cdot \nabla v -(b \cdot \nabla u) v\big) d x.\tag{1}$$

Lax-Milgram requires 
$$a(v,v) \geq \|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2,$$
to get which, if we manipulate the advection term in (1) a little bit:
$$
-\int_{\Omega}(b \cdot \nabla v) v d x=-\int_{\Omega} \nabla v\cdot (b v) d x
= \int_{\Omega} v \operatorname{div} (b v) d x = \int_{\Omega} \operatorname{div} b\; v^{2} d x+\int_{\Omega}(b \cdot \nabla v) v d x,
$$
yields
$$
-\int_{\Omega}(b\cdot \nabla v) v d x=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} (\operatorname{div} b)v^{2} d x.
$$
Hence in order to use Lax-Milgram, $\operatorname{div} b$ cannot be too negative.

Comment: Yeah I messed up the first part, you’re right. But in the second part I wanna be sure about a thing: what is the bilinear form you’re considering?

Comment: @tommy1996q $a(u,v)$ defined earlier in (1).